# Back from presentViewController distorts the screen - ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I'll give an overview of what I am trying to achieve:

1) There is screen1 on which there is a header on navigation bar.

[image]

2) On a button click, I am adding screen2 (it doesn't have a nav bar) as a child view controller on the first screen

Code for presenting screen2 upon a button click in screen1

```
Screen2ViewController *controller = [Screen2ViewController controllerStoryboard:STORYBOARD_NAME];
[self.navigationController addChildViewController:controller];
[controller viewWillAppear:YES];
```

On screen 2, there is a transparent view (yellow color) on the top which comes above the header of screen 1.
[image]

3)  Screen2 again presents a child view controller (Screen3ViewController - doesn't have a nav bar) which contains the table. (This was the requirement as there are 2 tabs - hidden - which need to show different controllers when tapped)

```
 Screen3ViewController *fp = [Screen3ViewController controllerStoryboard:STORYBOARD_NAME];
[self addChildViewController:fp];
[self.controllerView addSubview:fp.view];
[fp didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

4) When clicked on tableviewcell, screen4 appears which has a nav bar.

[image]

Problem - when I click on the cross button of screen4's nav bar, the screen gets popped as expected but the old view distorts a little. The start of screen2 shifts below by 50 pixels from the nav bar bottom of screen1. I am confused what is causing this behavior. Is it because some controllers have nab bar and some don't?

[image]

I tried a dirty hack of which I am not proud of (its not working as well)

Code for pushing screen4 when a cell is pressed on screen3

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Screen3ViewController *mController = [Screen3ViewController controllerStoryboard:STORYBOARD_NAME2];
    mController.media = media;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mController animated:YES];
}
```

back button click

```
- (void) goback: (id) sender {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

EDIT:

Screen shot of storyboard

Screen2: I have hidden some part of text. Those are 2 tabs. And the huge space below is for adding the 3rd view controller

[image]

Screen3: It contains a table view

[image]

Screen4:

[image]

Screen1 and screen4 extend a CustomNavController with code:

```
@implementation CustomNavController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColorFromRGB(0).CGColor;
```

}

On the other hand, screen2 and screen3 directly extend UIViewController

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem, please give feedback

Comment: Hey! Thanks for looking into the question. I have edited the question a little. There are 4 view controllers actually. Anyway, I tried that approach of yours of setting the frame but it didnt work :(

Comment: Can you show the storyboard screen shot?

Comment: Of which controller?

Comment: I think you are currently using two storyboards, if possible both

Comment: added snapshot of storyboard

Comment: On screen 2, there is a transparent view (yellow color) on the top which comes above the header of screen 1, why do you need this view, if you remove this view what is the result?

Comment: I am going to add shade to this view - will vary the opaqueness. That's why I need it so the old header a little greyed out

Comment: If you remove this view, what is the result?

Comment: Let me try. But why should it make a difference? If I remove it, I will add a blank space and I won't be able to see the head of old view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151862/discussion-between-user1000-and-astha-gupta).